# kendo automatic validation on form submit: how to attach to event

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, events, kendo-ui

I am using `Kendo DatePicker` and other Kendo widgets in my forms.
By changing an input of those widgets to an invalid value,
the form is beeing prevented from submit.
It appears that there is some kind of automatic validation, that is beeing triggered before the form is beeing submitted.
How can I e.g. add an event to this validation?

I want to stop my button spinners when this happens.

I thought of attaching something like this:

```
onPreventInValidFormSubmit(){
    Ladda.stopAll();
}
```

any ideas?

Update:

```
  <div class="form-horizontal" style="margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
            <div class="form-group" style="margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0">
                <div class="control-label col-sm-2 sl-internal-data">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CreatedAt)
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    @Html.Kendo().DateTimePickerFor(m => m.CreatedAt).Enable(true)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.CreatedAt)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

which is contained in `Ajax.BeginForm` with a `submit button`

Answer (score 0):

You could attach to the `validateInput` event, like this:

```
<form>
    <input name="username" required /> <br />
    <button id="save">Save</button>
</form>

  <script>
    // attach a validator to the container
    $("form").kendoValidator({
        validateInput: function(e) {
            if(!e.valid){
               Ladda.stopAll();
            }
        }
    });
  </script>
```

There is also a validate event, which fires only when the form is submitted and not after each field is changed. You can read more about these in the events section of this documentation article: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/validator#events-validateInput

Comment: I am not using kendoValidator and I don't want to use it. I rather want to know where the automatic (jQuery?) validation comes into play an how I can add my event there.

Comment: Technically, you are using kendoValidator - that's what the kendo widgets use when they validate against data types or the annotations of your model, etc. So my original answer still applies to you - just include the script portion and it should work for you.

Comment: Okay thx. This means I'll have to update each view that containts forms with submit buttons. Could I use this snippet in the layout view? I'd expect problems by loading content dynamically where those forms validators would not make use of this snippet...? thx

Comment: You can put it in the layout view and wrap it in an "if" statement that checks whether the validator is null to avoid exceptions on pages without forms, like this: if($("form").kendoValidator) { ... }

Comment: thx. Considering this demo http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/validator/index I think I'll always have to create an instance of the validator first